# Is there a way to detect if another process in vista is running in 32bit or 64bit mode?

Tags: windows-vista, 64-bit, 32-bit, detection

I'm writing an application that interacts with other processes on a x64 Vista machine. In order to do this it will need to know if the other process is running in 32bit or 64bit mode. How can I detect this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to get a process handle first, then call [IsWow64Process()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684139(VS.85).aspx).  If it's a 32-bit process, it'll return false.

Note that you'll also have to call [GetProcAddress()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683212(VS.85).aspx) to make sure that [IsWow64Process()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684139(VS.85).aspx) is even available in case you're not even running on a 64-bit Windows.

Cheers!
Sean